# Accessing rain from returned openweathermap json data

Tags: java, android, json, openweathermap

This is my `JSON`,

```
{
  "city": {
    "id": 2961297,
    "name": "Swords",
    "coord": {
      "lon": -6.21806,
      "lat": 53.459721
    },
    "country": "IE",
    "population": 0
  },
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.3535,
  "cnt": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1481025600,
      "temp": {
        "day": 284.68,
        "min": 284.68,
        "max": 285.36,
        "night": 285.36,
        "eve": 284.8,
        "morn": 284.68
      },
      "pressure": 1028.26,
      "humidity": 95,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "speed": 9.01,
      "deg": 186,
      "clouds": 92,
      "rain": 0.5
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access the rain value "rain": 0.5 as seen in the returned `JSON` data above I am unsure how exactly to do this as I don't have much experience working with `JSON` data.

This is my code,

```
JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
JSONArray ListArray = topLevel.getJSONArray("list");
weather = String.valueOf(ListArray);

for(int x = 0;x < ListArray.length();x++) {

    JSONObject myObj = ListArray.getJSONObject(x);
    myObj.getInt("rain");
    Log.d("TODAYS Rain"+rain,"");
    //System.out.Print("Current Weather" +id+main+icon+dscription+rain);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What comes into your log now?

Comment: It was returning all the content from the JSON data but telling that rain was not there when i tried to appened it to a textfield i have since fixed it Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

JSONArray listArray = topLevel.getJSONArray("list");
JSONObject firstObject = (JSONObject)listArray.get(0);
Double rain = firstObject.getDouble("rain");
System.out.println("TODAYs rain :" + rain);

     }
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to parse a Json is to use POJO classes that map the Json into an object instance.

You define the class structure and it gets filled with the data retrieved.

There is a guide on that same topic on this website: http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-how-to-parse-json-in-android-with-gson/

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
JSONArray ListArray = topLevel.getJSONArray("list");
weather = String.valueOf(ListArray);

for(int x = 0;x < ListArray.length();x++) {
    JSONObject myObj = ListArray.getJSONObject(x);
    myObj.getDouble("rain");
    Log.d("TODAYS Rain"+rain,"");
    //System.out.Print("Current Weather" +id+main+icon+dscription+rain);
}
```

You just need to use myobj.getDouble("rain") instead of myobj.getInt("rain") as the value of rain is not integer.